# Why is Double Dragon Arcade so different than NES version

Tags: version-differences, double-dragon-2-the-revenge

I grew up playing **DD2: The revenge** in the NES. I consider to my one of the best beat em up the system has to offer.

I got really surpised to find out how choppy the gameplay is in the arcade.

Is anyone aware of what happened here? How come the NES got such a better version?

Comment: Can you provide any examples of what specifically about it is "choppy"?

Comment: http://forum.arcadecontrols.com/index.php?topic=53606.0

Comment: So, are you asking about the arcade version, like the "xbox live arcade" version, or the "$2 to play" version?